# Moving an Android Studio project causes an error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I moved an Android Studio project that used Gradle from `D:\old\file\path` to `D:\new\file\path` and now I'm getting the following error:

`Installation failed with message Invalid File: D:\old\file\path\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk`

I tried uninstalling the app from my phone and still got the same error. I also tried an emulator but that didn't work either.

Comment: clear the project and rebuild it again

Comment: @statosdotcom that didn't work

Comment: you mentioned it below, please delete the post

Answer (score 10):

Close your project. Using your system file manager, delete all `.iml` files you have inside your project folder (probably this will be few files, two or three). This is the point where you instruct your A.S. to forget the older path.

Then import - not open - import your project on a brand new window of your Android Studio.

From the `File` menu, use `Invalidate caches and restart`. Clean Build and run again.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

**Build -> Clean Build** worked